PHP MP4.to API usage
I am trying to convert an av1 file to mp4, however, i cannot seem to get it to work.
I am using an apache2 webserver to serve the php file.
Here is the documentation link.
Here is my code:
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

$headers = array("Authorization: [my_api_key_redacted]");
$file_list = ["to_convert.mp4"];

function download_file($url, $filename, $api_url){
    $curl = curl_init();
    $url = $api_url.trim($url, "/");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    $error = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
    # Make sure destionation path exists
    $destination_path = "/video/";
    $destination_file = fopen($destination_path . $filename, "w+");
    fwrite($destination_file, $data);
    fclose($destination_file);
}

function convert_files($file_list, $headers, $convert_to) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.mp4.to/apis/");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $content = json_decode($content);
    $api_url = $content->api;
    $post_data["lang"] = "en";
    $post_data["convert_to"] = $convert_to;

    foreach ($file_list as $index => $file) {
        $post_data["file[$index]"] = curl_file_create(
            realpath($file),
            mime_content_type($file),
            basename($file)
        );
    }

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url."/v1/convert/");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return array(json_decode($content), $api_url);
}

function get_results($params, $api_url, $headers) {
    if ($params->error) {
        print_r($params->error);
        return;
    }

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url."/v1/results/");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_decode(json_encode($params), true));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $content = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
    curl_close($curl);

    if ($content->finished == false) {
        if (intval($content->queue_count) > 0) {
            print_r("queue: $content->queue_count");
        }

        sleep(5);
        $results = get_results($params, $api_url, $headers);
        return;
    }

    foreach ($content->files as $f) {
        download_file($f->url, $f->filename, $api_url);
    }
}

$convert_to = "av1-mp4";
list($resp, $api_url) = convert_files($file_list, $headers, $convert_to);
get_results($resp, $api_url, $headers);
?>

The folder layout is: 
/var/www/html/video [this is the location I want the converted files to go]
/var/www/html/testConvert.php [code location]
/var/www/html/to_convert.mp4 [this is the av1 file - it has an mp4 extension but i have confirmed that going to a site and manually converting av1 --> mp4 allows the video to be used how I need, so I need the API to do the same]
I've tried using absolute locations (/var/www/html/[etc] instead of just [etc]) but that doesn't seem to work either. I'm not seeing any PHP errors, it just doesn't do anything.<br>
Requested Edits:
var_dump($resp);echo gettype($resp);

returns

object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["error"]=> string(179) " 
" ["domain"]=> string(19) "api3.mp4.to" ["params"]=> object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["key"]=> string(32) "[my_api_key_was_here]" ["file_count"]=> int(0) } } object 

Also sometimes when refreshing it returns this:

object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["uuid"]=> string(32) "08c34dfa64944e219d9ae0ac4e17768a" ["domain"]=> string(3) "api" } object 

No idea what it is, that's not my API key, and I don't know why it sometimes shows up when refreshing, maybe its a different return from some other behavior.
Edit2: when i add this:
echo "Content: <br>";
echo $content;
echo "<br>End Content<br>";


between
curl_close($curl); and 
return array(json_decode($content), $api_url);
this is the output:
Content:
{"error": "\n\n\n\n \n\n\n
Not Found
The requested resource was not found on this server.
\n\n\n", "domain": "http://api3.mp4.to/", "params": {"key": "e777f6c236164ae8b9b26e03485b41d3", "file_count": 0}}
End Content

The API is returning a JSON string which you're then decoding to a PHP object and failing to read properly. Please post the raw JSON string so that we can see the error message it includes.

@TangentiallyPerpendicular is the edit i added what you were looking for, or was it something else?

If you running it locally for personal needs, you could use ffmpeg for which I have the code to utilize as I've recently converted video formats using it VIA PHP. Takes awhile for large files... but if you want to offer a service for other people to use than I don't recommend it.

@ezw That is what i am doing in the meantime - i am using an oracle cloud instance - it works, but its a little on the slower side - i assume a company which offers conversion as their entire service will provide faster conversion times - the download speed shouldn't matter since the instance has insane download speeds, the conversion time is the main limiter, so that's why i am trying to get this API working - that and I already spent some money on it so i would like to be able to use it T.T

@ezw I have it so i can enter a link, it parses the page for the download link, then automatically downloads the file, starts the conversion, and then deletes the original file after the conversion is done - the whole workflow is already done, im just trying to get the api working so i can drop it in the place of the ffmpeg conversion since its slow
